# Add SKSpriteNode children back to the parent after removing

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I'm working on a game that has 3 clouds in the background which are each SKSpriteNodes. In order to create a parallax effect I'm moving them down the screen as the character is moving up (the screen is moving up as well).

I removing them in the update method after they reach the bottom of the screen. I would like to add them back at a Y position 20px above the viewable scene so that would be 500x on an iPhone 4 and 588px on a iPhone 5. Then just repeat over and over.

Then only way I can think of to do this is to chain SKActions and run a sequence, but I don't think that is the best way. I'm trying to find a way to add them back after they have been removed in the update method.

```
  -(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size { 

         ...

       //Moving Clouds
    [self performSelector:@selector(createClouds) withObject:nil afterDelay:.2];

  }

 -(void)createClouds {

    SKSpriteNode *cloud1 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"cloud1"];
    cloud1.position = CGPointMake(40, 200);
    cloud1.xScale = .5;
    cloud1.yScale = .5;
    cloud1.name = @"Cloud1";
    cloud1.zPosition = 0;

    SKAction *moveCloud1 = [SKAction moveToY:-20 duration:15];
    [cloud1 runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:moveCloud1]];

    [self addChild:cloud1];

    SKSpriteNode *cloud2 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"cloud2"];
    cloud2.position = CGPointMake(300, 320);
    cloud2.xScale = .5;
    cloud2.yScale = .5;
    cloud2.name = @"Cloud2";
    cloud2.zPosition = 0;

    SKAction *moveCloud2 = [SKAction moveToY:-40 duration:15];
   [cloud2 runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:moveCloud2]];

   [self addChild:cloud2];

   SKSpriteNode *cloud3 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"cloud3"];
   cloud3.position = CGPointMake(200, 450);
   cloud3.xScale = .5;
   cloud3.yScale = .5;
   cloud3.name = @"Cloud3";
   cloud3.zPosition = 0;

   SKAction *moveCloud3 = [SKAction moveToY:-200 duration:20];
  [cloud3 runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:moveCloud3]];

  [self addChild:cloud3];

 }

 -(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {
     ....
    // Remove Cloud from parent
        [self enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"Cloud1" usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop) {
            if (node.position.x < 0 || node.position.y < 0) {
                [node removeFromParent];
                //Add node back to the scene at a Y position above the screen then move
                // the cloud downwards again. Repeat Forever.
                // Exp:  Move Cloud 1 to X position 40, Y position 500 (20 pixels above the top of the screen for an iPhone 4s)
            }
            else {
               // Do something?
            }
        }];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an SKAction to move your cloud back to the top:

```
    SKSpriteNode *cloud1 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"cloud1"];
    cloud1.position = CGPointMake(40, 200);
    cloud1.xScale = .5;
    cloud1.yScale = .5;
    cloud1.name = @"Cloud1";
    cloud1.zPosition = 0;

    SKAction *moveCloud1 = [SKAction moveToY:-20 duration:15];
    // SKAction to move cloud back to top of screen
    SKAction *moveToTop = [SKAction moveToY:CGRectGetHeight(self.frame)+20 duration:0];
    SKAction *cloud1Action = [SKAction sequence:@[moveCloud1, moveToTop]]; 
    [cloud1 runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:cloud1Action]];
```

You won't need the code in the update method.

Comment: This ended up working great! I don't know why I was against doing it this way.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can simply change the position

Also, use CGRectGetMinY to use relative positioning, easier to manage different screen sizes.

And check only the Y position too, because X won't change if they're moving vertically.

This is my idea:

```
 -(void)update:(NSTimeInterval)currentTime {

    for(int i = 1; i<=3; i++){
        NSString* cloud = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cloud%d",i];
        [self enumerateChildNodesWithName:cloud usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop) {
            if (node.position.y < 0) {
                node.position = CGPointMake(node.position.x,CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame)+20);
            }
        }];
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer seems like it would work, but it's not. I've added a NSLog statement after `node.position = CGPointMake(node.position.x,CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame)+20);`, it's not firing in the console.

Comment: and if you put an NSLog at the beginning of the update method it's called?

Comment: Yes, I put the NSLog in the beginning of the update method and it was called, but the clouds did not move. Thanks for the help anyway.